# Script to compare two results on C program

Tags: bash

If I print two results in a C program that need to be the same number, but there is 1% chance that one of the numbers is different, and I want to run it 100 times. But instead of doing it by myself, I want to test it automatically with a script. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `for i in {1..100}; do ./a.out > output; cmp expected output || break; done`

Comment: please provide an example what you have so far.

Comment: I would have thought something like `for i in {1..100}; do ./a.out | read a b ; if [ $a != $b ] ; then echo "$a != $b"; fi; done`